# Как исправить ошибки внутри cef и закрыть renderer subprocess?

Tags: c++, subprocess, render, chromium

в компьютерной игре я использую CEF для создания красивого современного графического интерфейса, и все работает нормально, но есть одна проблема. Когда я открываю cef_console.log я вижу эти многочисленные ошибки.

```
[0724/131653.949:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(315)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_INVALID_ENUM: Invalid attachment when a user framebuffer is bound.
[0724/131658.227:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(315)] [.DisplayCompositor] GL_INVALID_ENUM: Invalid attachment when a user framebuffer is bound.
```

Но игра не вылетает и все работает нормально, но есть еще одна очень неприятная проблема, после закрытия игры один подпроцесс игры не закрывается, я думаю, это связано с этими ошибками (аргумент командной строки этого подпроцесса type=renderer). С чем может быть связана эта проблема и как я могу ее решить? Я использую рендеринг, написанный на dx12, а также C++20

Я попытался изменить параметры командной строки cef, а также изменить настройки, но ничего не помогло. Главная проблема в том, что я даже не понимаю, почему это происходит. Поиск информации в интернете не дал никаких результатов.

Comment: пожалуйста добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), по "симптомам" практически невозможно найти ошибку в вашем коде.

Comment: я не могу сделать хороший пример, потому что у меня много кода связанного с игрой, все что мне нужно, причины появления такой ошибки (хотя бы теоритические) с остальным, думаю, я смогу разобраться. (или скажите какую именно часть реализации сефа вам показать, чтобы я смог добавить только необходимый код)

Comment: Почему вы не пишете какая у вас OS ?

Comment: ну так если dx12 то очевидно что виндовс 10, разве нет?